# How to add module to add system call for linux kernel 5.17.7

Tags: c, linux

in my kernel's `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl`, there is its content:

```
# ...

447     common  memfd_secret            sys_memfd_secret
448     common  process_mrelease        sys_process_mrelease
449     common  futex_waitv             sys_futex_waitv
450     common  set_mempolicy_home_node sys_set_mempolicy_home_node

#
# Due to a historical design error, certain syscalls are numbered differently
# in x32 as compared to native x86_64.  These syscalls have numbers 512-547.
# Do not add new syscalls to this range.  Numbers 548 and above are available
# for non-x32 use.
#
512     x32     rt_sigaction            compat_sys_rt_sigaction
513     x32     rt_sigreturn            compat_sys_x32_rt_sigreturn

# ...
```

As you see, no system call's id is `451` and I want to create a linux module, which can add a system call, named sys_helloworld and its id is `451`.

Following a book (the book is for kernel 4.16.10 but my kernel's version is 5.17.7), I write code below:

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Peterlits Zo 1927405082");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Just Hello World");

#define NUM 451
#define SYS_CALL_TABLE_ADDRESS 0xffffffffb1600240
#define HW_INFO "[helloworld INFO] "

int orig_cr0;
unsigned long *sys_call_table_my = NULL;
static int (*anything_saved)(void);

static int clear_cr0(void) {
        unsigned int cr0 = 0;
        unsigned int ret;
        asm volatile("movq %%cr0, %%rax" : "=a"(cr0));
        ret = cr0;
        cr0 &= 0xfffffffffffeffff;
        asm volatile("movq %%rax, %%cr0" :: "a"(cr0));
        return ret;
}

static void setback_cr0(int val) {
        asm volatile("movq %%rax, %%cr0" :: "a"(val));
}

// SYSCALL_DEFINE0(helloworld) { // sys_helloworld
asmlinkage long sys_helloworld(void) {
        printk(HW_INFO "Hello world, from Peterlits Zo (1927405082)\n");
        printk(HW_INFO "pid: %d, comm: %s\n", current->pid, current->comm);
        return current->pid;
}

static int __init helloworld_init(void) {
        printk(HW_INFO "Hello World From Module Helloworld by 1927405082.\n");
        sys_call_table_my = (unsigned long*) (SYS_CALL_TABLE_ADDRESS);
        anything_saved = (int (*)(void)) sys_call_table_my[NUM];
        orig_cr0 = clear_cr0();
        sys_call_table_my[NUM] = (unsigned long) &sys_helloworld;
        setback_cr0(orig_cr0);
        return 0;
}

static void __exit helloworld_exit(void) {
        printk(HW_INFO "Byebye From Module Helloworld by 1927405082.\n");
        orig_cr0 = clear_cr0();
        sys_call_table_my[NUM] = (unsigned long) anything_saved;
        setback_cr0(orig_cr0);
}

module_init(helloworld_init);
module_exit(helloworld_exit);
```

There are some macros:

- `NUM`: The id of the new system call.
- `SYS_CALL_TABLE_ADDRESS`: I run `sudo cat /proc/kallsyms | grep sys_call_table` to get its address.

It is easy to get its meaning:

- Set the cr0 to make the kernel's memory to be writable.
- Write the system call table.
- Set back the cr0.

So I try to compile this module and install:

```
# In Makefile
obj-m += helloworld.o
PWD := $(CURDIR)

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

```
# In bash
$ make
$ sudo insmod helloworld.ko
zsh: killed sudo insmod helloworld.ko
```

I do not know why zsh want to kill my process, but the module is now in my kernel:

```
$ lsmod
Module       Size      Used by
helloworld   16384     1
efivarfs     16384     1
```

And I cannot remove it:

```
$ rmmod helloworld
rmmod: ERROR: Module helloworld is in use
$ rmmod -f helloworld
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove 'helloworld': Device or resourcee busy
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove module helloworld: Device or resource busy
```

But it looks failed and I cannot call the 451 system call:

```c
long a = syscall(451); // -> -1
```

The log is:

```
May 20 13:24:56 PeterlitsArchVm kernel: [helloworld INFO] Hello World From Module Helloworld by 1927405082.
May 20 13:24:56 PeterlitsArchVm kernel: RIP: 0010:helloworld_init+0x17/0x1000 [helloworld]
May 20 13:24:56 PeterlitsArchVm kernel: Modules linked in: helloworld(O+) efivarfs
May 20 13:24:56 PeterlitsArchVm kernel: RIP: 0010:helloworld_init+0x17/0x1000 [helloworld]
May 20 13:27:25 PeterlitsArchVm dbus-daemon[234]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.home1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.home1.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=0 pid=809 comm="sudo rmmod helloworld" label="kernel")
May 20 13:27:25 PeterlitsArchVm sudo[809]: peterlits : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/peterlits/proj/linux/01-01-模块，但是是HelloWorld ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/rmmod helloworld
May 20 13:28:10 PeterlitsArchVm dbus-daemon[234]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.home1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.home1.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=812 comm="sudo rmmod -f helloworld" label="kernel")
May 20 13:28:10 PeterlitsArchVm sudo[812]: peterlits : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/peterlits/proj/linux/01-01-模块，但是是HelloWorld ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/rmmod -f helloworld
```

And something looks not good (Why there is `sys_call_table_my`):

```
$ cat /proc/kallsyms | grep sys_call_table
0000000000000000 D sys_call_table
0000000000000000 D ia32_sys_call_table
0000000000000000 b sys_call_table_my    [helloworld]
```

---

@craig-estey Hello, I try to use `long` for `cr0`, but it still do not work:

```
-int orig_cr0;
+long orig_cr0;
 unsigned long *sys_call_table_my = NULL;
 static int (*anything_saved)(void);

-static int clear_cr0(void) {
-       unsigned int cr0 = 0;
-       unsigned int ret;
+static long clear_cr0(void) {
+       unsigned long cr0 = 0;
+       unsigned long ret;
        asm volatile("movq %%cr0, %%rax" : "=a"(cr0));
        ret = cr0;
        cr0 &= 0xfffffffffffeffff;
```

Comment: Just a guess: Did you read back the memory location to verify that the memory array element was actually changed? Are there any inter CPU caching issues?

Comment: You should look at `native_write_cr0` in `arch/x86/kernel/cpu/common.c`. Amongst other things, it has a `"memory"` clobber. Also, why not use the `X86_CR0_WP` define instead of hardcoding?

Comment: In your CR0 manipulation, you're using `int` (32 bits), but would `long` be better since things might get truncated if in 64 bit mode?